# How to run a function on some route which is written in the same file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

What I want is to run a function on some route that function is written inside the same file.

```
module.exports.controller = function(app) {
    app.get('/folders/create', createDirectory);
}
var createDirectory = function(path, name, permissions, version, type)
```

Comment: You need to move the declaration before calling the function. Or to give the function a name instead of declaring it in variable, like: `function createDirectory(...){...}`

Comment: @Ziki function is already declared before the call.

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to do this but the parameters of your function must be `req` and `res`:

```
function someFunction(req, res) {
  res.send('goldfish are nice');
}

module.exports.controller = function(app) {
    app.get('/folders/create', someFunction);
}
```

the function you define has to actually deal with the request, otherwise the browser will just load forever and you'll eventually time out.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I want to create list of default directory on '/folders/create' route for this i have create a function with parameters like directory path, directory name, permissions etc. How i will acheive this